# How do I autoincrement Xamarin Android build and version numbers in Azure Pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, xamarin.android, yaml, azure-pipelines, version

I looked at the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/xamarin-android?view=azure-devops) and couldn't find much,

> Xamarin.Android
> Build an Android app with Xamarin
> task: XamarinAndroid@1   inputs:
> #projectFile: '**/*.csproj'
> #target: # Optional
> #outputDirectory: # Optional
> #configuration: # Optional
> #createAppPackage: true # Optional
> #clean: false # Optional
> #msbuildLocationOption: 'version' # Optional. Options: version, location
> #msbuildVersionOption: '15.0' # Optional. Options: latest, 16.0, 15.0, 14.0, 12.0, 4.0
> #msbuildFile: # Required when msbuildLocationOption == Location
> #msbuildArchitectureOption: 'x86' # Optional. Options: x86, x64
> #msbuildArguments: # Optional
> #jdkOption: 'JDKVersion' # Options: jDKVersion, path
> #jdkVersionOption: 'default' # Optional. Options: default, 1.11, 1.10, 1.9, 1.8, 1.7, 1.6
> #jdkDirectory: # Required when jdkOption == Path
> #jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64' # Optional. Options: x86, x64

It feels like I am missing something since incrementing the version and build is required by Google Play Store and will need to be done on each release by everyone.

**How do I autoincrement Xamarin Android build and version numbers in Azure Pipelines?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set this in manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="string"
          android:sharedUserId="string"
          android:sharedUserLabel="string resource" 
          android:versionCode="integer"
          android:versionName="string"
          android:installLocation=["auto" | "internalOnly" | "preferExternal"] >
    . . .
</manifest>
```

You can use [token replace extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) as follows:

```yaml
variables:
  major: 1
  number: $[counter(variables['major'], 100)]

steps:
- bash: echo $(minor)
- task: qetza.replacetokens.replacetokens-task.replacetokens@3
  displayName: 'Replace tokens'
  inputs:
    targetFiles: |
      **/AndroidManifest.xml
```

with file like this:

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="string"
          android:sharedUserId="string"
          android:sharedUserLabel="string resource" 
          android:versionCode="#{number}#"
          android:versionName="string"
          android:installLocation=["auto" | "internalOnly" | "preferExternal"] >
    . . .
</manifest>
```